# boost odeinit issue: "no viable overloaded '-='

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I am trying to create a boost odeint parser. I can get a solution for doubles from the equation, but I need one which works in (3D) points ( I am using this as a learning curve to a kepler orbital solver), and I am getting:

> ```
> no viable overloaded '-='
> ```

The no viable overload error from the compiler points to line 261 in `operators.hpp`, which is:

```
BOOST_BINARY_OPERATOR_NON_COMMUTATIVE( subtractable, - )
```

Minimal code that causes this error is below. Note the Point3D is taken from the lorenz_point code in odeind.

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

class point3D :
    boost::additive1< point3D ,
    boost::additive2< point3D , double ,
    boost::multiplicative2< point3D , double > > >
    {
    public:

        double x , y , z;   
        point3D() : x( 0.0 ) , y( 0.0 ) , z( 0.0 )
        { }  
        point3D( const double val ) : x( val ) , y( val ) , z( val )
        { }
        point3D( const double _x , const double _y , const double _z ) : x( _x ) , y( _y ) , z( _z )
        { } 
        point3D& operator+=( const point3D &p )
        {
            x += p.x; y += p.y; z += p.z;
            return *this;
        }    
        point3D& operator*=( const double a )
        {
            x *= a; y *= a; z *= a;
            return *this;
        }
};


int main()
{
    point3D x;
    point3D dxdt =  x - x;
    
    // Suppress unused variable warning.
    (void) dxdt;
}
```

Comment: A syntax error does not warrant posting your complete code. Post just enough code to reproduce the error, and no more. (Try to compile the [mre] yourself to make sure it still produces the same error.) At a guess, in this case you might need the definition of `model`, a definition of `state_type`, and whatever `#include` lines are utilized by those two definitions.

Comment: Hi, I put all of the code in the original post, and was told just to put only minimal code in the post: hence this is a cut down version. What is the best way of achieving the desired goal.. this is my 1st post

Comment: @ColinThomas "Cut down" does not mean "in pieces". One way to evaluate if you have a [mre] is to copy the chunk of code into an online compiler, for example [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/), hit the "Run" or "Compile" button, and get your error message.

Comment: It looks like one big simplification you could do is dump `struct model`, as all you should need from that is the problematic line. And the line itself could be trimmed down. I'll edit your post with an example of a [mre] and leave it up to you to confirm that it is the same error you are seeing on your end (my error message differs from yours, but that might just be due to a different compiler being used).

Comment: Also, I would advise against arguing "This is not a syntax error, but a compiler error". A compiler error suggests that the compiler is taking valid code and producing incorrect results. That is not the case here. On the other hand, "compile-time error" would be a more correct term than "syntax error" for what I wrote earlier; while syntax errors are compile-time errors, not all compile-time errors are syntax errors. That is a correction you could make. It doesn't change my point that complete code is not warranted, though. Hence, my advice against trying to make it a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like:

changing:

```
dxdt[1] = - (0.9+0.7*t)*x[1] - (m_K*x[0]);
```

to

```
dxdt[1] = -1.0 * ((0.9+0.7*t)*x[1] + (m_K*x[0]));
```

seems to sidestep the compiler issues....

Answer (score 0):

While the error message is confusing due to the library's implementation (not a compiler issue), the culprit is straight-forward. You are attempting to use functionality that has not been defined.

Your `point3D` class supports addition of two `point3D` objects and multiplication of a `point3D` object by a `double`. It does not support subtracting two `point3D` objects. When you try to subtract them, you get an error.

If you were to add `operator-=` to `point3d`, your code would compile. The definition would be very similar to `operator+=`.

```
    point3D& operator-=( const point3D &p )
    {
        x -= p.x; y -= p.y; z -= p.z;
        return *this;
    }
```

I would consider this an oversight in the design of `point3d`. If addition is defined, it is natural to expect subtraction to also be defined. It's a bit annoying when it is not (unless there is a good reason to prohibit subtraction).

Comment: So in the end, I agree "syntax error" is not a great description of this error. It seems to be more of a "programmer error" or (if `point3D` has documentation) "failure to follow the documentation". Still, "compilation error" might be the best term to use here, as it does not try to assign blame. ;)